# Pulling all Wordpress pages into one page with page templates

Tags: wordpress

I would like to be able to pull all of the pages from my custom theme into one page template, but still allow all of the pages to be displayed according to the selected page template.

In other words, if I have a page template called 'Main' where I pull all of the page data into, and I create a page called 'Home', I would like this page to display on the 'Main' template according to the page template I have selected for the 'Home' page. Is this possible to do?

Thanks,
JW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so I am going to answer my own question here. I did some research on my own and modified some code from an tutorial to Ajaxify a theme. What needs to happen is this.

In your page.php file, or whatever template you want to use as your main page template, add this.

```
<?php query_posts( array('post_type'=>'page', 'posts_per_page' => 1000, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC') ); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

    <?php 
        global $post;
        $slug = $post->post_name;
        locate_template(
            array(
                "template-$slug.php",
                'template-main.php'
            ), true
        );
    ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Then add your page templates to the theme, and name according to the page slug i.e. template-about.php, or template-home.php. You can then have all of your content displayed dynamically in a one page site and be able to use the default Wordpress pages. I hope I was clear on this, and if not, feel free to let me know, and I'll do my best to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

use in all your page templates this:

```
include 'page.php';
```

and then in page.php you can use this:

```
if (is_page_template('page_temp_one.php')) { ... }
```